# How to add a bounce effect, when you click on the div (Part 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already explain this discussion in the part 1 topic.
[Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059480/how-to-add-a-bounce-effect-when-you-click-on-the-div), if you need to re-think my topic.

This was solved, but I have some issues about the JavaScript.

In the last topic, he resolved my issue.

John S answered to my topic:

> > If your arrow element has the ID "toggle", you could do.
> >
> > > And here is the code, he provided:
> > >
> > > ```
> > > $(document).ready(function () {
> > >         $("#toggle").click(function () {
> > >         var $panel = $('#panel');
> > >                 if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
> > >                         $panel.slideUp("slow");
> > >                 } else {
> > >                         $panel.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
> > >                 }
> > >         });
> > > });
> > > ```

This is what I wanted, but when you click the text and when you have it at the bottom of the page and if you have a footer over top of it then when you click the text, you got to scroll manually, I do not like this. I want it flow automatically, which means when you click the text, it will bring you the content, without scrolling through the content.

Please tell me, how to achieve the scrolling bug.

Comment: If you want your footer to be unobtrusive, set a few containers. Your `main` container should have a `negative margin` equal to it's `static height` and your footer should have an `absolute position` of `bottom:0;`. That will make it so nothing in your body will overlap.

Comment: @NicholasHazel, I do not get what you mean. Can you explain more, like a demo or something.

Comment: To be quite honest, I would have posted an answer, but I don't know what you mean. Care to show a working example of the problem you're facing?

Comment: @NicholasHazel, It's a Theme so, I can't give it to you but I can explain more about what's happening. When you have the footer at the very bottom and above it, you have the newsletter footer that hides the information so, when you click the text, it will slideDown with the information and that's where you get the scroll manually.

Comment: Why not use `slideUp` instead...?

Comment: @NicholasHazel, I am, it's using two affects slideUp and slideBottom. Explain more, if I didn't get your question.

Comment: Show me a live version, or move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @NicholasHazel, All it is a footer with content and above it, it's just the newsletter footer with content inside of it but it's hidden then, when you click it, it put's up the content.

Comment: So it doesn't slide down the content?... perhaps I'm missing the problem.

Comment: @NicholasHazel, it does slide the content but the problem is, when you click it, it doesn't flow automatically, you got to scroll manually to see the content.

Comment: Honestly, I'm here to help, but this is getting convoluted, and without even a screenshot or real world example, I can't really help. I would delete this question and reformat your wording to get an appropriate response.

Comment: @NicholasHazel, Sorry for the late response. I have gathered some pic's of how it will look. [Screenshot(1)](http://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/16/52/46/02/screen10.png), you will see the footer and the newsletter toggle. [Screenshot(2)](http://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/16/52/46/02/screen11.png), you will see the open newsletter with information inside. When you click the toggle text, it puts up the information, like screenshot(2), I have not yet scroll down yet. It looks like that when you click the text so, basically when you click the "Click me" text, it will overflow the footer and the newsletter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am juggling answers and this appears to be **Not an appropriate question**. Please delete this thread and ask again with more **specific** insight to the problem at hand.